# navigation bar border isn't changing colour

Tags: html, css

I want to change the colour of the border on my navigation bar but it ain't working for me.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
        <title> site </title>
      </head>
    <style type="text/css">
body 
    {
      background-color:#75b5d6;
      color:white;
      font-family:"Arial";
      text-align:center;
    }
      a:link
    {
      color:white;
    }
      a:visited
    {
      color:white;
    }
      a:hover
    {
      color:white;
    }
      a:active
    {
      color:white;
    }
.nav
    {
      border:3px solid white;
      border-width:0px;
      list-style:none;
      margin:2;
      padding:2;
      text-align:center;
      background-color:orange;
      font-family:"Bookman Old Style";
    }
    .nav li{
    display:inline;
    }
.nav a
    {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    }
h1
    {
      font-size:40;
      font-family:"Lucida Handwriting";
    }
h2
    {
      font-size:27.5;
      text-decoration:underline;
    }
p
    {
      font-size:12;
    }
    </style>
      <body>
        <h1> Kevril.net </h1>
        <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="x">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="x">site1</a></li>
        <li><a href="x">site2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <p>Hellow</p>
      </body>
</html>
```

what did i do wrong? Is it something in the css part or the html? I would be very happy if you can help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the .nav class.  If so, you have:

```
  border:3px solid white;
  border-width:0px;
```

Make sure it has a width and you'll see the colour you set.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `border-width:0px;` in your style for `.nav` which is making your border not appear. Remove that line (you set your width in the shorthand `border` definition anyway) and it should work.

It's handy for these kind of things to use a developer tool such as Chrome's "Inspect Element" to help you work out what style's breaking it.

(IE has "Developer tools" and Firefox has something similar built in, or you can install firebug)

Answer (score 0):

That's because on `.nav` you've specified `border-width:0;`.

That's effectively rendering your border with no width, even though you specified `3px` in your `border` style.

Take that off and it works.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cVNwn/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-width:0px;` from your `.nav` and it should work

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zRQdj/